# can't find running process which I started via SSH yesterday

Tags: debian, ssh, process, virtual-machine

Yesterday I connected to my Developer VM Debian Linux via SSH.
I started "Mamute" which is a open source stackoverflow clone etc.
As I restarted my machine today I reconnected as root and wanted to restart mamute. So first I wanted to kill the process.

```
$ ps all
```

does not show me any process which is the mamute one. But Mamute is still running on a Port 8080 and I can use it.

So what is the magic here? Where can I find that process?
I also tried to login as the normal user but no luck there aswell.

Comment: Try `netstat -antp|grep 8080|grep LISTEN` to get the PID of the process which listens on port 8080.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But why wasn't the process listed in "ps" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `ps al`, it (by default) lists all processes with a controlling terminal (tty).  It’s most likely that the process you started was “[daemonised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)” to dissociate it from the terminal you were using when you started it.

If you include the `x` option, `ps` lists processes without a controlling terminal, e.g., `ps alx` displays all processes for all users running on your system. Its output includes the terminal (TTY) associated with each process, using a question mark for daemon processes.